# How can I call my toString function to my main function?

Tags: c++

At the moment, my program loops and allows the user to input account info as many times as they want. However, when 2 is entered the account information displayed is that of the last input and not multiple inputs (accounts). I have a feeling i need to use push.back somewhere to send the user input to the vector but unsure.

```
CertDeposit::CertDeposit()
{

}
CertDeposit::CertDeposit(double In_Principal, int In_AccountNumber,
    string In_FirstName, string In_LastName,
    double In_InterestRate, double In_DepositYears,
    int In_NumCompounding)
{
    Principal = In_Principal;
    AccountNumber = In_AccountNumber;
    FirstName = In_FirstName;
    LastName = In_LastName;
    InterestRate = In_InterestRate;
    DepositYears = In_DepositYears;
    NumCompounding = In_NumCompounding;
}
double CertDeposit::getAccumulation() const
{
    return Accumulation;
}
double CertDeposit::getInterestAccrued() const
{
    return InterestEarned;
}
const string CertDeposit::toString() const
{
    ostringstream buffer;
    buffer << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Account Number: " << getAccountNumber() << endl
        << "Name: " << getFullName() << endl
        << "Original Deposit: $" << getPrincipal() << endl
        << "Annual Interest rate: " << getAnnualInterestRate() << endl
        << "Number of years of deposit: " << getDepositYears() << endl
        << "Number of times compounded per year: " << getNumCompoundings() << endl
        << "Total accumulation: $" << getAccumulation() << endl
        << "Interest accrued: $" << getInterestAccrued() << endl;
    return buffer.str();
}
// All function starting with word get ONLY Have one line of code!
// That code is just one return statement.
// See Savitch to see how to write get functions.
double CertDeposit::getPrincipal()const
{
    return Principal;
}

const string CertDeposit::getFirstName() const
{
    return FirstName;
}

const string CertDeposit::getLastName() const
{
    return LastName;
}

const string CertDeposit::getFullName() const
{
    return FirstName, LastName;
}

int CertDeposit::getAccountNumber() const
{
    return AccountNumber;
}

double CertDeposit::getDepositYears() const
{
    return DepositYears;
}

int CertDeposit::getNumCompoundings() const
{
    return NumCompounding;
}

double CertDeposit::getAnnualInterestRate() const
{
    return InterestRate;
}

void CertDeposit::setLastName(string In_LastName)
{
    throw "To be completed";
int main()
{
    vector<CertDeposit> CDVec;
    string FirstName, LastName;
    int  AccountNumber, NumCompounding, x = 0, i;
    double Principal, InterestRate, DepositYears, Accumulation, InterestEarned;

    cout << "This program would demo certificate of deposit account in a bank." << endl;

    while (x < 5) {
        cout << "********* Main Menu ***********" << endl;
        cout << "1. Add a new Certificate of deposit account to the CertDeposit Vector:" << endl;
        cout << "2. Print all certificate of deposit accounts to console:" << endl;
        cout << "3. Print all certificate of deposit accounts to an output file" << endl;
        cout << "[User would be asked for the output file full path]:" << endl;
        cout << "4. Sort CertDeposit Vector based on account number in ascending order:" << endl;
        cout << "5. Exit" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        cout << endl;

        switch (x) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter account holder's first name:" << endl;
            cin >> FirstName;
            cout << "Enter account holder's last name:" << endl;
            cin >> LastName;
            cout << "Enter account number [whole number only]:" << endl;
            cin >> AccountNumber;
            cout << "Enter amount of original deposit:" << endl;
            cin >> Principal;
            cout << "Enter annual interest rate. For example for 7.2% enter 0.072:" << endl;
            cin >> InterestRate;
            cout << "Enter number of years for certificate of deposit:" << endl;
            cin >> DepositYears;
            cout << "Enter number of times interest is compounded per year" << endl;
            cout << "[whole number only]: ";
            cin >> NumCompounding;
            break;
            CDVec.emplace_back(Principal, AccountNumber, FirstName, LastName,
                InterestRate, DepositYears, NumCompounding);
        case 2:
            for (size_t i = 0; i < CDVec.size(); i += 1)
            {
                CDVec[i].toString();
            }
            //cout << .tostring() << endl;
        case 3:
            cout << "Enter full path to output file: ";
            //cin >> 
            break;
        case 4:
            Sort(CDVec);
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        }
    }
    system ("pause"); // uncomment for Visual Studio 2017
    return 0;
}

inline bool operator<(const CertDeposit & a, const CertDeposit & b)
{
    return a.getAccountNumber() < b.getAccountNumber();
}
void Sort(vector<CertDeposit>  &CDVec)
{
    sort(CDVec.begin(), CDVec.end());
}
```

Comment: You are correct. You need to add to the `vector`, but you may find [`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) a simpler route than `push_back`. As for where to put it, after where you have gathered all of the information, but before you've lost the information.

Comment: Also, a good programmer always starts out with a simple example if they are not familiar with how to proceed.  For example: [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff2889791b79f943).  That simple example has a vector that requires an object to be added to it, and the object needs to be initialized with certain values -- no different than your example.

Comment: So two issues, first you have a vector of `CertDeposit` so you should create a CertDeposit object, using the constructor, and second you need to add the `CertDeposit` object to the vector, use `push_back` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Case 1 never creates an object of type `CertDeposit`, and you never place it into a vector. This is easy enough to fix. After you get all the data you need:

```cpp
CDVec.emplace_back(Principal, AccountNumber, firstName, lastName, 
                   InterestRate, DepositYears, NumCompounding);
// Requires C++11, shouldn't be an issue
// emplace_back will both create a CertDeposit object, and place into the vector
// Note that the arguments to emplace_back are identical to your constructor arguments
```

- Case 2 just prints whatever you entered last (you're printing variables, not information from a `CertDeposit` object, and definitely not from your vector), because again, you never actually store the information away. There's also no loop, so even if you stored it away, you'd only print one item. You'll need either a print function, or to overload the `operator<<()` function for `CertDeposit`.

```cpp
// pseudo-code(-ish)
for (auto i : CDVec) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';  // Assumes overloaded operator<<()
}
```

One note, your naming is not consistent. Names beginning with a capital letter are generally reserved for class or type names. You also alternate between camel-casing and underscoring, with no rhyme or reason. These things make your code harder to understand.

Minor quibble that could go either way, I don't see the point of your `Sort()` function if you are only ever going to call it in the one location. And unless you provided some function to compare `CertDeposit`s (usually by overloading `operator<()` [tangent to the aside, if you overload less than, you should overload all comparison operators]), it should break. Maybe it doesn't if the class is trivial, but I feel like it won't compile. If there is no single way to compare CertDeposits, i.e., different comparisons are viable, you can provide a lambda to `std::sort()` or just create different `friend` comparison functions in your class.

Comment: in this code why does it say: No operator "<<" matches these operands. Operand types are: std::ostream << CertDeposit.

// pseudo-code(-ish)
for (auto i : CDVec) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';  // Assumes overloaded operator<<()
}

Comment: The comment I left on that line explains it. If you didn't overload `operator<<()`, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you need to store the data somewhere if want to access them later as you suggested vector which is quiet suitable for this.
But importantly first you need to structure the data and store them as objects.

You will have to instantiate CertDeposit object every time you iterate and during case1 when you enter the data you need to add it to the object.
something like,

```
 CertDepoObj. Firstname = "Some value";
 CertDepoObj. AccountNo = "Some value";
```

Lastly you will have push the object into vector.

Inorder to sort the vector based on Account number you will have to write a separate comparator function which can be passed to sort function that will sort it.